# not able to clone or push existing project to gitlab

Tags: git, repository, gitlab

I have created one private repo, and I have the existing project on my laptop. I need to add the existing project to my repo. But when I do with terminal I am getting this below error :

```
remote: The project you were looking for could not be found.
fatal: repository 'https://gitlab.com/sathishchinniah/Taxi-App-User.git/' not found
```

Steps I followed :

```
**Existing folder
cd existing_folder
git init
git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/sathishchinniah/Taxi-App-User.git
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push -u origin master**
```

What would be an issue for this.Please help me out.Thanks

Comment: Just log in to gitlab, go to the repository, and follow the instructions to clone or to push/add remote.

Answer (score 17):

Below step solved my problem. In below command replace `username` with your GitLab username and `project` with your GitLab project name.

```
git remote set-url origin https://username@gitlab.com/username/project.git
```

After you try to push to the master using bellow command it will popup a window to add credential to the repository.

```
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are not referencing the repository as you should for gitlab. Instead of:

```
https://gitlab.com/sathishchinniah/Taxi-App-User.git
```

You should use:

```
git@gitlab.com:sathishchinniah/Taxi-App-User.git
```

Gitlab uses a single defined user for cloning, pushes and pulls (and every action related) and authenticates the action thru ssh keys. You should have one for the computer you are using (the one with your working copy) and register the key as a valid key for the repository on gitlab.

First, you need to have a user defined on your local git. If not, you can do as follows to configure yours:

1. Set up your name using `git config --global user.name "Your name here"`
2. Set up your email; the email must be enabled for the repository, and needs to have a private key added on the repository for permission purposes . `git config --global user.email "your@mail.com"`

Then you should create and register you key. I can further assist you with that too if you need.

Then, depending on what you want to do or how you want to start, you have a few options:

**Option 1**

Clone an existing repository:

1. Clone the repository: `git clone git@gitlab.com:namespace/project.git` where “namespace” is the namespace of your group of projects, or your gitlab user (if no groups are defined) and “project” is the name of your project over gitlab
2. Then you can simply add some files, commit them and push the commit by running: `git push -u origin master`

**Option 2**

Initialize the repository locally and then push the content to server:

1. Initialize the repository: `git init`
2. Add the remote: `git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:namespace/project.git` where “namespace” is the namespace of your group of projects, or your gitlab user (if no groups are defined) and “project” is the name of your project over gitlab
3. Then you can simply add some files, commit them and push the commit by running: `git push -u origin master`

**Option 3**

Use an existing local repository:

1. Rename the old origin (if necessary): `git remote rename origin old-origin`
2. Add the new origin: `git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:namespace/project.git` where “namespace” is the namespace of your group of projects, or your gitlab user (if no groups are defined) and “project” is the name of your project over gitlab
3. Push your branches: `git push -u origin --all` and `git push -u origin --tags` to push all tags

---

In your case you would like to use a new empty repository initialized locally and then push the content to repository:

```
git init
git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:sathishchinniah/Taxi-App-User.git
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push -u origin master
```

If it fails, please provide the errors. You should check also if you have a private key defined in your computer, and if the key is defined as a valid key for your repository at gitlab.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

## Approach #1

While cloning the code Gitlab, add your credentials in the URL:-

```
git clone https://{username}:{password}@gitlab.com/.../
```

But this is not good from the security perspective.

## Approach #2

If you are using windows, then delete the existing entries for gitlab in Windows Credential Manager. This is present under Control Panel.

[image]

After deleting the credential, clone the repository again, you should see a window asking for credentials.

In my case, the root cause is that I was trying to access the repository from a different account which was saved in Windows Credential Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a private repository, you'll need to provide credentials for this server. Try :

```
git remote add origin ssh://sathishchinniah@gitlab.com/sathishchinniah/Taxi-App-User.git
```

or

```
git remote add origin https://sathishchinniah@gitlab.com/sathishchinniah/Taxi-App-User.git
```

It should prompt for the password.

Comment: instaed of  this lne `git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/sathishchinniah/Taxi-App-User.git` i needs to use git remote add origin https://username@gitlab.com/username/repo.git

Comment: Try the examples I added (your username not "username"). Make sure you don't have a / after .git

Answer (score 1):

This is happen you have more than one account configured in any code editor like android studio or vs code, so before pushing you have to use your username before your remote url like this

```sh
git remote set-url origin https://username@gitlab.com/username/project.git
```

and then

```sh
git push -u origin master
```

otherwise no need to add username, you can do as normally you are doing to push like below

```sh
git init
git remote add origin https://@gitlab.com/username/project.git
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push -u origin master*
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up your name using git config --global user.name "Your name here"

Set up your email; the email must be enabled for the repository, and needs to have a

private key added on the repository for permission purposes . git config --global user.email "your@mail.com"

before:

https://gitlab.com/{gitlab_user}/project_repo.git

after:

https://{gitlab_user}@gitlab.com/gitlab_user/project_repo.git

[more details](https://medium.com/@imstudio/gitlab-the-project-you-were-looking-for-could-not-be-found-issue-685944aa5485)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by,

```
git remote set-url origin https://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<gitlab host>/path/to/repo.git
```

For Example

```
git remote set-url origin https://Vikram:*********@gitlab.info.lab/testdemo/mydemo.git
```